# values, types, kinds,... as an infinite sequence?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, higher-kinded-types

I'm only beginning to become familiar with the concept of kinds, so bear with me if I am not formulating my questions well...

**Values have Types:**

```
3 :: Int
[1,2,3] :: [Int]
('c',True) :: (Char,Bool)
```

**Types have Kinds:**

```
the type 'Int' has kind *
the type '[Int]' also has kind *
   but the type constructor [] has kind * -> *
similarly, the type (Char,Bool) has kind  *
   but the type constructor (,) has kind * -> * -> *
```

**What do Kinds have?**

Do they kinds have ilk, or genres, or breeds, or varieties?

How far does this sequence of abstraction go?  Do we stop because we run out of words, or do we stop because going farther has no value?  Or, perhaps, because we quickly reach the limits of human cognition and just can't wrap our heads around higher-genred kinds?

A related question:  languages give us value-constructors (like a cons operator) to make values. Languages also give us type-constructors like (,) or [] to make types.  Are there any languages that expose kind-constructors to make kinds?

Another edge case that I'm curious about:  We apparently have a type that has no value, denoted as ⊥, called "the bottom type".  Is there a kind that has no type:  a bottom kind?

Comment: You might also be interested in [a question](http://vimeo.com/42399455?t=27m40s) somebody asked after José Pedro Magalhães' "More Well-Typed Than Ever" talk at the Dutch Haskell User Group Day 2012. The question is asked at 27 minutes, 40 seconds into the video.

Comment: Does not answer your questions but a [good description of kinds](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo)

Comment: The traditional word for what kinds have is "sorts", but once you start classifying sorts the lack of uniform treatment of uniform concepts starts bugging you and you invent dependent types.

Comment: Thank you @luqui for giving me the word "sort".  It looks like there is at least one research language out there that played with this idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\Ωmega

Comment: My 5-minute window to try to get that URL right has expired.  Copy & paste this one: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ωmega`

Comment: @pohl Coq also has an infinite tower of sorts: the sort Type(j) contains Type(i) for all i < j. See http://coq.inria.fr/doc/Reference-Manual006.html#toc28

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The terminology `type` and `kind` does not scale well.  Type theorists since Bertrand Russell have used a hierarchy of "types."  One version of this has that `Integer : Type 0, Type 0 : Type 1, Type 1 : Type 2, ..., Type n : Type (n+1), ....`  In dependently typed languages like Coq and Agda, one frequently needs these "higher sorts."

Levels like this are helpful for avoiding [Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).  Using `Type : Type` tends to cause contradiction (see [Quine](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine-nf/) for alternative designs).

This use of numbers is the standard notation when we need it.  Some type theories have a notion of "cumulative kinds", "cumulative levels" or "cumulative sorts" which says "if `t : Type n` then also `t : Type (n+1)`".

Cumulative levels + "level polymorphism" give a theory almost as flexible as `Type : Type`, but avoids paradoxes.  Coq makes the levels implicit mostly, although the sorts `Set` and `Prop` are both typed `Type`, `Type {1} : Type {2}`.  That is, you don't usually see the numbers, and most of the time it just works.

Agda has a language pragma which provides level polymorphism, and makes things very flexible, but can be slightly bureaucratic (Agda is however usually less "bureaucratic" than Coq in other areas).

Another good word is "universe."

Comment: So in other words 'self-referentiality is of course a problem' when working with abstractions like types.

Comment: @AndreasScheinert:  no.  "Unfoundedness" is a problem.  Types are ordinals and therefore recursion schemes.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably read Tim Sheard's paper about Omega, a dialect of Haskell with an infinite tower of types/kinds/sorts, but without full-blown dependent types.  It explains why you'd want this, and mentions that the levels above "sort" are in practice (at least so far) not directly used very much.

Comment: Is this paper available somewhere by URL or would I have to climb through the stacks at my local university library?